# Rendering mountains around a tile layer

Tags: tilemap, three.js, tiled

When making a 2D Pokémon game, I just faked elevation by putting mountain tiles underneath the land. Now my tiles are 3D models, so I'm using layer properties to define their elevation. What I don't know though is how to generate a 'mountain' around them.

The tilemap is kinda' like this:

```
Layer 1: Layer 2: Layer 3:
....     \\\\     \\\\
....     \..\     \\.\
....     \..\     \\\\
....     \\\\     \\\\
```

Layer 2 has y-offset set to 1, and Layer 3 has y-offset set to 2. All they do right now is float in the air. What I'm trying to do is render a mountain around them.

Comment: What have you tried? What does it mean to "add mountains?" Do you just need to know how to put them in your sprite sheet? How to generate them in a level? Et cetera.

Comment: Sorry! I made *some* progress, but I'm stuck again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 3D ""tile"" objects.

During Loading read your 2D tile map and wherever there's a mountain tile paste your 3D mountain object over it.

You can make this very fancy and detect the size of mountainous areas pasting various large mountains objects.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing right now =). I have a tilemap, and for each tile, I place an object that whose size and vertical offset in the obj file.

What I meant was - how could I put, say, a "grass" tile on that mountain?

Comment: You'll have to use multiple tile layers then.

Comment: Any idea how I'd go about making the mountain underneath the grass? =)

Comment: You'll need to change the texture on the mountain for this or make 2 mountain "tiles".

Comment: Okay so I just ended up using some basic array manipulation to get the corners of the 'mountain' and change the model for those. Thanks for the answer and elaboration!